# By which criteria range is applied to arrays and strings in C#8?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

I'm looking through C#8 ranges and cannot understand how exactly the application of the Range is restricted to arrays and strings only.

I have thought that it is somehow related to interface array implements. It implements `ICloneable, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, IStructuralComparable, IStructuralEquatable, IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>` but when I cast `new int[0]` to any of them and try to use range on it, the compilation error appears (either Cannot apply index or Cannot convert from Index to int).

Is it somehow hardcoded to be used with arrays and strings only or I've missed something?

Comment: The CLR lives by different rules then we do. Its just the case some C# features require specific types from the framework. For example, interpolated strings are based on the `FormattableString` class. The `foreach` statement makes use of `IEnumerable`, and `IEnumerator` interfaces. The using statement makes use of the `IDisposable`interface.

Comment: Haven't played with C#8 yet... but have you tried an `int[1]` or something larger? Seems to me that a range cannot be specified over an array with zero elements, since the lower and upper numbers represent the start and end indices.

Comment: if you need something else, why not `Span<T>`

Comment: Ranges uses a new struct (Index) and are implemented by the use of extension methods, so probably the extension methods are only defined for few types( array, strings). For more details you can lookup: https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2018/07/24/indexesandranges/

Answer (score 0):

Only the types that originally support `Count` (or `Length`) and `Item[int index]` properties could support `Item[Index index]` and `Item[Range range]`. This includes arrays, `List`, string, `Span`, etc.

As for those types that does not support accessing items by index, it is reasonable that they do not support indexes and ranges.

Comment: IReadOnlyList<T> has all of those